# Can I combine columns and function on columns with plyr?

Tags: r, plyr

I don't know why this code that is trying to group events based on an id and with bigger granularity fails using the plyr library:

```
times <- as.POSIXct("1970-01-01")+1:100
vals <- sample.int(2,100,replace=TRUE)
df <- data.frame(times,vals)
ddply(df, .(vals,round(times,"mins")), function(x)nrow(x))
Error in if (n > 2^31) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What's your sessionInfo()? It works for me, with a warning.

Comment: Work for me. What R/plyr versions are you using? I'm on 2.14 and plyr_1.6. No warning for me.

Comment: > sessionInfo()
R version 2.12.1 (2010-12-16)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=C              LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] plyr_1.7

Comment: You better first upgrade to the latest R version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that is a bug of R 2.12. Upgrading to 2.14 solved the problem. Thanks for the hint.